# Let $x,y,z>0; ~ xyz(x+y+z)=1$. Show that $(x+y)(y+z)\ge 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Assuming positive real values of $x,y,z$, and that $ xyz(x+y+z)=1$, how can we prove that $(x+y)(y+z)\ge 2$

I tried using the AM-GM inequality but as if I were looping. I'm not sure if C-S or other inequality methods could help.  Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(x+y)(y+z)=xy+y^2+zx+yz=y(x+y+z)+zx=\frac y{xyz}+zx=zx+\frac1{zx}\ge 2\sqrt{\frac1{zx}zx}=2$$ using A.M.$\ge$ G.M. for $z,x>0$

Comment: I reached until $zx +\frac{1}{zx}$ but never thought of completing your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tariq, welcome, hope I could make things lucid.